# Azure functions CosmosDB attribute in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I`m trying to make working pilot project with Azure Functions and CosmosDB input binding.
I have updated my Visual Studio 2017 to latest pack (15.5.5). Also I have installed latest Azure Functions SDK.

After I have added to Azure Functions project new CosmosDB trigered function I see the following picture after build:

[Error after build in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGctY.png)

[Nuget packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVn6a.png)

There are no any documentation about CosmosDBTrigger. Maybe you met this class before and can tell me where to find this magic lib in nuget, which will work for me (in which this CosmosDB attribute is defined)?

PS: DocumentDB attribute from azure web jobs SDK not working at all, as soon as if function has this attribute azure don`t see this function at all.
Queue binding functions works for me ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CosmosDBTrigger` attribute is introduced only in version `1.1.*` of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB` NuGet package.

Unfortunately, this version is still in beta (`1.1.0-beta4` as of today), so you need to tick `Include prerelease` checkbox in your Visual Studio to use it.

Comment: Thank you. It solved issue with build, but attribute still not recognized by Azure. Still no firing on adding document in CosmosDB collection. But I think I need to wait for release. Any plans when it will be ready?

Comment: It should work today, probably some configuration is not correct somewhere